# Where can I learn APL?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I want to learn APL (more specifically Dyalog APL), but I can't seem to find any good sources to learn from.

The only source I could find was [Dyalog's Documentation Downloads](http://www.dyalog.com/documentation_library.htm), but other than that, can anyone recommend a good source?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to learn APL? What use do you have for it? I have never found a good reason to use it other than that you can create really short (although cryptic) code.

Comment: Dyalog Programming Contest 2009: http://www.dyalog.com/contest2009/

Comment: @Zifre codegolf.stackexchange.com could be a reason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a scan of [APL: An Interactive Approach](http://scanserver.ulib.org/is/scanserver/book24/xml/doc.scn?rs=1&br=0.0&rt=0&rp=http%3A%2F%2Fscanserver.ulib.org%2Fis%2Fscanserver%2FBrowseList.asp%3FgroupId%3Drefmanual&pg=1&auth=752b47040a02a7ee50&x=0&y=0).

Comment: This is a great, if dated, book to learn from.

Comment: Definitely dated, but the best source that I have found so far.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work anymore. Anyone have an updated link?

Comment: Thankfully, there are used copies sold all over the internet for a few $.

Comment: There are used copies of this on Amazon for $0.50 (though it's $4+ with shipping/tax)

Answer (score 4):

Look for the tutorial on http://aplwiki.com

It offers a taster. With the Open Source APL NARS2000 you do not have to spend a buck on an APL interpreter. For getting seriously into APL, go for APLX or Dyalog.

Watch out! You will get addicted quite soon - or not.

Answer (score 3):

Python script to download all the scans:

```
def download(url, filename):
     import urllib
     webfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
     file = open(filename, 'w')
     file.write(webfile.read())
     webfile.close()
     file.close()

for i in xrange(1, 390):
     download('http://scanserver.ulib.org/is/scanserver/book24/tiff/apli%.4d.tif?rs=1&br=0.0&rt=0' % i, 'apl%.4d.tif' % i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The K&R book for APL is probably "An Interactive Approach" by Gilman and Rose but there are lots of other books, tutorials, exercises, puzzles, processors and links listed on the [APL Wiki](http://aplwiki.com/)